# Washing fruit after cutting?

Tags: fruit, cutting, peeling

Today, I cut up some pineapple. On the bare fruit that was left after cutting, there was residual pieces of the skin, so I washed the pineapple. To me, it seemed like I was washing off juice from the pineapple, which seems negative. However, I also didn't want to eat random pieces of skin.

First, how much of the juice am I washing off when I rinse after cutting, and is it enough for me to be able to taste a difference? Second, when cutting pineapple or fruit in general, how can I avoid having small leftover particles on the bare fruit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is - you can't avoid the little particles like the hairs from the flower bits when you cut a pineapple. Washing is the quickest way to get these residual pieces off the fruit - and yes, you do wash a little of the juice away, but this will be generally replaced by more juice in a short period of time, from where you cut the fruit (assuming the fruit is a juicy one and ripe).

Other options : a gentle scrape of the pieces off with a knife or other edged implement - but this requires you to closely observe the whole fruit and generally to pick them off a few at a time. You can also pat down with a paper towel, but this often doesn't work very well.